# Does sound check on the iPhone have album mode

Tags: iphone, music, sound-volume, album

I know that iTunes sound check on the Mac has album mode, but does sound check on the iPhone have album mode as well?

Comment: Please let us know which version of iOS and which device you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Yes, I am pleased to tell you that Sound Check respects both the track gain as well as the album gain (album mode).

---

### How to use it

Go to `Settings > Music > Playback` and enable Sound Check.

[image: image of the Sound Check setting in iOS]

Please be aware that Sound Check's **Album Gain** it only works if you

- **play an album directly**

  - (`Library > Artist > 'Album Title' > Play`)
- **play an album directly**

  - (`Library > Artist > 'Album Title'`)
- play **all albums by an artist**

  - (`Library > Artist > Play`)
- play **all albums by an artist** shuffled

  - (`Library > Artist > Shuffle`)

---

This enables Sound Check's **Track Gain**:

- the song appears in a playlist

  - even if you exclusively add all tracks of an album a play it in the correct order
- you play a single song using (Spotlight) Search

---

### Validation

To understand the algorithm in iOS' Music.app I have tested it with an iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.3 and iOS 11 beta 5 and two albums from the iTunes Music Store (iTMS):

- Pink Floyd - The Dark Side of the Moon *(1973)*
- Led Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin (I) *(1969)*

SC = Sound Check

Examples:

Led Zeppelin's song **Communication Breakdown** (track 7)

- `Library > Artist > 'Album Title' > Play` SC on: Volume is higher
- `Library > Artist > 'Album Title' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is higher

---

- `Library > Playlist> 'SC test LZ' > Play` SC on: Volume is lower
- `Library > Playlist> 'SC test LZ' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is lower
- `Library > Playlist> 'Sound Check test' > Play` SC on: Volume is lower
- `Library > Playlist> 'Sound Check test' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is lower

---

---

Pink Floyd's song **Money** (track 5)

- `Library > Artist > 'Album Title' > Play` SC on: Volume is higher
- `Library > Artist > 'Album Title' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is higher

---

- `Library > Playlist> 'SC test LZ' > Play` SC on: Volume is lower
- `Library > Playlist> 'SC test LZ' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is lower
- `Library > Playlist> 'Sound Check test' > Play` SC on: Volume is lower
- `Library > Playlist> 'Sound Check test' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is lower

---

---

Pink Floyd's song **Brain Damage** (track 8)

- `Library > Artist > 'Album Title' > Play` SC on: Volume is higher
- `Library > Artist > 'Album Title' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is higher

---

- `Library > Playlist> 'SC test LZ' > Play` SC on: Volume is higher
- `Library > Playlist> 'SC test LZ' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is higher
- `Library > Playlist> 'Sound Check test' > Play` SC on: Volume is higher
- `Library > Playlist> 'Sound Check test' > Shuffle` SC on: Volume is higher

Note:

- The playlist called 'SC test LZ' only contains Led Zeppelin's 1969 album.
- The playlist called 'SC test PF' only contains Pink Floyd's 1973 album.
- The playlist called 'Sound Check test' contains Led Zeppelin's and Pink Floyd's album.

[image: Technical information for track 5 of Pink Floyd's album 'Dark Side of the Moon' as shown in iTunes]

Additional resources:

- iTunes' behavior with Sound Check turned on explained by Bob Katz ([Hydrogenaudio forums](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?PHPSESSID=hs91jn5pa0dgmnvodj0a166sh5&topic=103986.msg863377#msg863377))
- Apple's [documentation for 'Mastered for iTunes'](https://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/docs/mastered_for_itunes.pdf) (2012) (PDF)

Comment: Thank you for taking you time to answering my question and for giving so much information.

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'll see if I can find other scenarios when a track's album gain will be ignored/applied.